# Why does Access demand a parameter for my query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

AgencyID produces an output, but not the output I need. I need to create the query without having to enter a parameter value.

I've tried ()"" even put the Y separate from the 68 and even tried concatenation

```
SELECT AgencyID, Description, DonationID, DonationDate
FROM Donation
WHERE Description='Computer Equipment' OR AgencyID='Y68'
ORDER BY AgenyID, Description;
```

Output I'm receiving, but need to create the query automatically without parameter box

[image]

Comment: can you post desired i/p o/p sample

Comment: what is the expected output of this?

Comment: Like it is it's AgencyID. IF I PUT(),[], or "" around Y68 name changes to Y68

Comment: Your `ORDER BY AgenyID, Description` AGENCYID is spelled wrong.

Comment: Thank you I've been stuck on this for 2 days. I checked spelling on WHERE line but never thought thought to look at next line. i just assumed it was because of the string and numeric value combo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `ORDER BY` clause AgencyID is spelled wrong. That's why Access is prompting you.

```
SELECT AgencyID, Description, DonationID, DonationDate
FROM Donation
WHERE Description='Computer Equipment' OR AgencyID='Y68'
ORDER BY AgencyID, Description;
```

[image]